# Any jQuery plugin like the Yahoo Profile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a website that user must add some data like date, place e.t.c. and I saw Yahoo Profile having this cool thing where you can add for example your name by just clicking on that specific area. My question is if anyone knows a similar plugin or how should I start to build this?

My goal is to let user input and submit it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the yahoo profile but it looks like [JEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) can get you started.